# How to export agent data from Dialogflow Essentials to Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

Is it possible to export Agent data from Dialogflow Essentials to Dialogflow CX? If "yes" then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to export agent data from Dialogflow Essentials and import it to Dialogflow CX.

[Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs) uses new features -  flows and pages which gives us a clear and explicit control over a conversation. Because of this, the structure of Dialogflow CX is different compared to the exported agent data in Dialogflow Essentials.

What you can do is to create an agent from scratch in Dialogflow CX and re-apply the design you have in Dialogflow Essentials.

**Note:** The design you have in Dialogflow Essentials needs to be adjusted based on Dialogflow CX concepts: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/basics